# How to use rows from a table as columns of the result in a query which fetches from multiple tables?

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have the following query to generate a particular report

```
SELECT DATE,
NVL(SUM(P_A),0) AS P_A,
NVL(SUM(P_B),0) AS P_B,
NVL(SUM(P_C),0) AS P_C,
NVL(SUM(P_D),0) AS P_D
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT
     D.ORG,
     D.TYPE,
     D.ID
     D.PART
     D.QTY 
     TO_CHAR(H.ACTUAL_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')
     AS SHIP_DATE,
     CASE
         WHEN D.PART = 'A'
         THEN 
             NVL(D.QTY,0)
         END AS P_A,
     CASE
         WHEN D.PART = 'B'
         THEN 
             NVL(D.QTY,0)
         END AS P_B)
     CASE
         WHEN D.PART = 'C'
         THEN 
             NVL(D.QTY,0)
         END AS P_C,
     CASE
         WHEN D.PART = 'D'
         THEN 
             NVL(D.QTY,0)
         END AS P_D
      FROM V_DTL D, O_HDR H
      WHERE D.ORG='ABC'
      AND D.TYPE IN ('XYZ')
      AND H.ID = D.ID
      AND H.STATUS = 'PQR'
      AND H.ACTUAL_DATE =>
      TO_DATE ('20171001', 'YYYYMMDD')
       AND H.ACTUAL_DATE <
      TO_DATE ('20181002', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

I got to know today that there is actually a table say 'Task_Dtl' which has all the parts (A,B,C,D) I'm using in case statements. and can be linked to both tables in the query using fields(Org, part etc.)

My question here is, Is there a way I can use this table to get rid of the hard coding in the query(case statements). The challenge is that these are rows in the table but I need them as columns for my result set.

I looked at the pivot operation but realized it is used when changing **ONE** table's rows to columns or vice versa. But I need to use the other tables here for qty etc. IS it possible to use pivot here? IF yes, How? otherwise. IS there another way we can achieve this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could perform the pivot operation in a CTE or a subquery and then join it with the other tables.

Comment: I joined the Task_Dtl table in the subquery and applied the PIVOT operation(on the sub query) after removing the case statements. It worked and I was able to get the same result.

Comment: Good job coming up with the solution yourself. Please add an answer to this question which explains what you did and how you did it, including an example of the SQL you wrote, so that others can see how to do this. Then please accept your own answer. Thanks.